# Listing inner-department seminars/presentations that focused on presenting current research by other authors?

Tags: cv

At my university there are weekly seminars where faculty or students can do presentations for the department.

I had done several of these during my time as a graduate student, although admittedly they were seldomly composed of original work.  They were often taking a recently published paper and presenting the findings, sketching the proofs, and illustrating how it applies to research you are interested in and/or doing.

I started to list these on my CV as a more generic "Department Seminar Presentations" of a given paper/topic, but as I thought about it more I began to wonder if this is actually improper to do?

This is in mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's *improper* per se, but I would not include them.

These sorts of presentations are more akin to assignments for a class: they can improve your skills in terms of public speaking and also getting deeper into the material.

However, you wouldn't put your course assignments on a CV, and I wouldn't put these presentations on a CV either.

I wouldn't even include them if they were based on original work, unless they are in a format that indicates some level of acceptance or prestige: conference presentations, invited talks at other institutions, etc. Instead, you reference that original work where it appears in public: in publications, for example.

They *might* be appropriate in a more generic form in a non-academic CV, when the point is to emphasize your experience presenting these sorts of things to a public audience, rather than your academic credentials.

Comment: I actually really agree with your point of being "more akin to assignments for a class", but would your stance still be as firm regarding someone who is *not* a graduated PhD and yet to reach public works?

This section is really more to be a mark of filling a CV as being a "comprehensive statement of your educational background, teaching, and research experience" and try to aid in addressing those three things that public works would otherwise, much more appropriately, fill.

While they did require *some* approval from either the faculty or graduate cohort, they were in no-way prestigious

Comment: @OGV You know, it might be a bit different for math given how delayed your research output tends to be compared to people in my field. If you meant it to highlight some of the academic work you are doing as a student, to say apply for a grant while still a student, then maybe that content would be worthwhile in a CV for that purpose. I also wouldn't characterize my stance as being too 'firm', except for the part about what I myself would do :) - so take the advice with a grain of salt. Your advisor is also a good person to run this question by.

Comment: I'd also say I'd be more likely to add it if you feel like you really did some original work in the interpretation of the papers you are presenting, which is something that also might be more special (though not exclusive) to math. If you are taking a published work and turning it into something truly digestible to a broader audience, that's a lot more relevant than just summarizing a paper in what my field would think of as a "journal club" presentation.

Comment: And lastly I'd echo @Buffy's "they could be omitted or reduced to a single line" as an option - in that case I think you avoid making it look like you are embellishing something if you just lump it in as "N Department Seminar Presentations..."

Answer (score 1):

I would think it is fine, provided that you think the talks would be interesting to others outside your department. The heading you suggest is appropriate, showing that they were local. And, if you are interested in a career as an educator, primarily, rather than a researcher, they might be especially valuable.

If you are able, in these talks, to focus on insights and not just details, they would probably be especially useful as talks to students - even undergraduates.

I doubt that they would add a lot, and if your CV needs to be short they could be omitted or reduced to a single line (Several departmental talks...).

But, I can't see how it is improper in any way. Not everything in a CV has the same impact, of course and different people will look for different things.